# Regex - Repeating negative character classes?

Tags: javascript, regex

To put it simply, I have the regular expression: `/[^0-9]+/gi`

It is not stored as a string, but as a JavaScript regular expression. In other words, without quotation marks. My intention is to return an array of character classes consisting of characters that are **not** digits.

I expect to return this array when given the code: `/[^0-9]+/gi.exec("rgb(123, 124, 125);");`

However I only receive an array of `length: 1` with index `[0]` being `"rgb("`. Why am I not getting an array consisting of the other non-digits like `);` or `,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) several times:

> If the match succeeds, the `exec()` method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.
>
> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can **use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string**. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's [`lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) ([test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) will also advance the [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property).

```js
var re = /[^0-9]+/g; 
var str = 'rgb(123, 124, 125);';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.write(m[0] + "<br/>");
}
```

Perhaps, for the current regex `match()` is really more efficient, but looking forward, [MDN advises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> if you want to obtain *capture groups* and the global flag is set, you need to use `RegExp.exec()` instead.

That is why IMHO `exec` is a more flexible method.

Comment: If you ask me, `exec` is more flexible, and in case you need to perform any operations with the matches/captured texts, `exec` is the most convenient method.

Answer (score 5):

> Why am I not getting an array consisting of the other non-digits

Because you are holding it wrong.

```
"rgb(123, 124, 125);".match(/[^0-9]+/gi);
```

---

`.exec()` always returns the next match, until there are no more matches - it is designed to be run in a loop.

Comment: use `/\D+/g` ... because `\D+` == `[^\d]+` == `[^0-9]+` ... and there's no need for `i` qualifier

Comment: @JaromandaX Absolutely. I've copied the OP's regex verbatim because the error was not in the regex but in the approach itself.

Comment: I understand - I was not criticising your correct answer